# how to pass txtbox value from a form to crystal report and print?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a "Create Check form" with text boxes and a datetimepicker. In form1 (CreateCheckForm), the user will fill the text boxes `Payee, Amount_in_Figure`, and `date` which will be printed out after clicking the `btnButton` right after filling those text boxes. Now, I want the text box values to be passed into my other form with crystal report so i can print it WITHOUT saving it yet to database, but whenever I click the button, nothing shows up in my crystal report. Just a blank page.. Below is my code:

This is the code behind the form with crystal report (form2):

```
    Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
    Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1

        Report1.SetParameterValue("amtinwords", frmCreateCheckURC.txtAmtInWords.Text)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
Report1.SetParameterValue("issuedate", frmCreateCheckURC.dtpDate.Text)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
Report1.SetParameterValue("?amtinfigure", frmCreateCheckURC.txtAmtInWords.Text)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
Report1.SetParameterValue("?payee", frmCreateCheckURC.txtAmtInWords.Text)
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
    End Sub
```

Parameter names are `amtinwords,issuedate,amtinfigure,amtinwords,payee`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "code is not working"? Doesn't compile? Doesn't set the values? Sets the wrong values? Can't access form1 controls from form2? Something else? (Also, you don't need to reassign the ReportSource every time, just do it once after adding all the values)

Comment: Sorry. What I meant was, nothing shows in my crystal report whenever I click the button. @stuartd

Comment: @Erica show me how do you pass your form1 data to form2

Comment: i was able to fix it this morning. thank you for replying tho :) @KinjalPatel

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to pass the data from form1 to form2 and then try to pass data to crystal report with your code

**Form1**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sTitle As String
    Dim sText As String
    sTitle = TextBox1.Text
    sText = TextBox2.Text
    Dim frm As New Form2(sTitle, sText)
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

**Form2**

```
Public Sub New(ByVal sTitle As String, ByVal sText As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Text = sTitle
    Me.Label1.Text = sText
End Sub
```

Comment: i was able to fix it this morning. thank you for replying tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem. The only problem is that I posted the code on the wrong place and form. The code should have been in `btnButton` 's .